# Photoshop SDK: Export plugin for Layer Comps

Tags: c++, plugins, export, photoshop

I'm currently looking into writing a complex photoshop export plugin in c++, the first step of which would be to recreate the functionality of the "Layer comps to files" script. After extensive searching, reading through the Photoshop SDK documentation and looking into the example plugins fund in the SDK, I'm no closer to even finding out if this is possible.

My question is the following: How can a Photoshop export plugin enumerate and apply Layer Comps in order to export them individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out Export plugins can't modify the document state, so the anwser to my original question is that it's not possible like that.

However you can create an Automation plugin that can apply the layer comps and then calls an Export plugin to save the resulting image. The SDK doesn't explain this process well, but there are two example plugins (the Listener and the Getter plugins) that dump C code that is useful to learn how to automate Photoshop.

The Listener plugin dumps code that replicates the actions you took (i.e. applying a layer comp or calling an exporter plugin)

The getter plugin dumps code that shows how to access all the variables in the system (i.e. the list of layer comps, and their names)

You will need to compile these plugins from the SDK before you can use them.

So the solution is to

1. Create an export plugin that exports to the format you'd like
2. Create an empty automation plugin that will do the scripting
3. Check what code the Listener plugin dumps when calling your export plugin directly - you can copy-paste that code to your automation plugin to call the export plugin
4. Check what code the Listener plugin dumps when applying a layer comp - this code will require the name of the layer comp as a parameter
5. Check the dump of the Getter plugin to see how to access the list of layer comps (it's the compsList member of the document which contains compsClass objects)
6. Check the dump of the Getter plugin to see how to access the title member of the compsClass objects in the list
7. Modify the code dumped by the Getter plugin to read data instead of setting it, and use it in the automation plugin to iterate through the layer comp list. Apply the layer comp in each iteration and call the export plugin to finally get the images.